# how to convert an image into base64 in xamarin.android?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, xamarin.android

I have this code, it works very well in android studio but not in xamarin 
**bitmap.Compress() has different arguments in xamarin** and i am confused how to convert image into base64 or binary in xamarin.android?

I am receving an error in the 3rd line:

> ( bitmap.Compress() has some invalid arguments).

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.ace1);
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100,bao);
byte[] ba = bao.ToByteArray();
string bal = Base64.EncodeToString(ba, Base64.Default);
```

Comment: Is this a compile-time error or an exception?

Comment: Both exceptions and compile time errors are errors. It's not clear which this is. It sounds like it's probably a compile time error, but you should edit your question to be clearer.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I believe it is a compile-time error, as per my experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for `Bitmap.Compress`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Graphics.Bitmap.Compress/p/Android.Graphics.Bitmap+CompressFormat/System.Int32/System.IO.Stream/) in Xamarin, you'll see that the last parameter is a `Stream`.

The equivalent of `ByteArrayOutputStream` in .NET is `MemoryStream`, so your code would be:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.ace1);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);
byte[] ba = stream.ToArray();
string bal = Base64.EncodeToString(ba, Base64Flags.Default);
```

(You could use `Convert.ToBase64String` instead of `Base64.EncodeToString` if you wanted, too.)

Comment: there is an error in line        byte[] ba = stream.ToArray();             stream cannot convert into byte[]

Comment: @EhsanUllah: Fixed - the declaration for `stream` should have specified a compile-time type of `MemoryStream`, as that's where `ToArray` is declared.

Comment: can you please clarify your answer jon?

Comment: @EhsanUllah: Not sure what you mean. I've edited the answer to specify the compile-time type as `MemoryStream` - it should now work fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet Using `using` is not recommended here? (_for `Bitmap` and `MemoryStream`_)

Comment: @MehdiDehghani: I wasn't focusing on that part... disposing of the Bitmap would probably be useful. There's no particular benefit in disposing of a `MemoryStream` except for the very rare situation of using remoting.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm getting a `Byte[]` for my `Bitmap` object:

```
Byte[] imageArray = null;
Bitmap selectedProfilePic = this.GetProfilePicBitmap ();

if (selectedProfilePic != null) {
    using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream ()) {
        selectedProfilePic.Compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, ms);
        imageArray = ms.ToArray ();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.